# Is there any known formula that gives the value of a factorial as a sum?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

> Is there any known formula for multiplying out factorials?

$x$ being a positive integer, $x!$ is defined as
$$x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1$$

My question is if there exists another "multiplied out" form of that product, as a sum.

I tried multiplying out the first three, four, five factors and seemingly random coefficients that seemed to get bigger and bigger the more factors I multiplied out appeared.

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343452/any-shortcut-to-calculate-factorial-of-a-number-without-calculator-or-n-to-1

Comment: Please be sure you format the question using mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed. This has to do with something called [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). The numbers you are looking at are
$$n!=n(n-1)\cdots (n-n+1)=\sum _{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n\brack k}n^k,$$
where ${n\brack k}$ is the number of permutations of $n$ having $k$ cycles.